# Long table spanning multiple pages page wide width in two-columns page (table showing over text)

Tags: latex, tabular

How to create a clongtable that spans over multiple pages with page width in a document of two columns page?
I have this so far:

```
 \documentclass[final,3p,times,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable, tabu}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}


\definecolor{aliceblue}{rgb}{0.94, 0.97, 1.0}
\definecolor{cornsilk}{rgb}{1.0, 0.97, 0.86}
\definecolor{eggshell}{rgb}{0.94, 0.92, 0.84}
\definecolor{floralwhite}{rgb}{1.0, 0.98, 0.94}
\definecolor{anti-flashwhite}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.96}
\definecolor{ivory}{rgb}{1.0, 1.0, 0.94}
\definecolor{lightyellow}{rgb}{1.0, 1.0, 0.88}
\definecolor{splashedwhite}{rgb}{1.0, 0.99, 1.0}
\definecolor{snow}{rgb}{1.0, 0.98, 0.98}
\definecolor{white}{rgb}{1.0, 1.0, 1.0}
    \definecolor{whitesmoke}{rgb}{0.96, 0.96, 0.96}


\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long table over multiple pages},
  label = {rct-tab},
]{
  colspec = {p{1.4cm} p{2.5cm} p{1.4cm} p{1.8cm} p{1.4cm} p{0.9cm} },
  rowhead = 1,
  hlines, 
  row{even} = {whitesmoke},
  row{odd} = {white},
  row{1} = {floralwhite},
} 
ID & P1  & P2 & P3 & P4 & P5 \\
1  &  x, age $\geq$ 18 & 62 (58) & 17.7\% (10.3\%) & 3 months & TY \\
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
\end{longtblr}
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
```

This code works fine and spreads the table over multiple pages but it shows up over the text. I think it is a floating problem. So when placed in a page with two-column it goes over the text.

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] which reproduces the problem

Comment: Edited, please see above.

Comment: :( does not compile. Doesn't have a class, doesn't show us how you created the columns, via the `multicols` package or as a class option, uses undefined colours, uses `&` outside of a table  .... :(

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the packages. updated.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind having a page break before and after your table, you could temporarily switch to one column mode:

```
\documentclass[3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{tabularray}  %  the basic package
\usepackage{afterpage}   %  to quasi-break 2 col layout
\usepackage{lipsum}      %  for text, decoration, highlights
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
    

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{A Long and wide table to break across pages}
\author{StackExchange}
\date{Some future time}

\begin{abstract}
    Long tables that break across pages are hard to make manually, 
    especially when they span the entire \texttt{\textbackslash 
    textwidth} of pages with two or more columns of text.
    However, the \texttt{longtblr} environment makes it
    easy for us.\\[1ex]  
    Hats off to those who put so much labour in building these
    packages so as to keep us trouble-free.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
    longtablr \sep tabularray \sep \LaTeX \sep documentation
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}


\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-2]
Morbi nam pretium at Drerit \ref{rct-tab}.


\lipsum[3-5]



\afterpage{
\onecolumn
\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long table over multiple pages},
  label = {rct-tab},
]{
  colspec = {p{1.4cm} p{2.5cm} p{1.4cm} p{1.8cm} p{1.4cm} p{0.9cm} },
  rowhead = 2,
  hlines, 
  row{odd} = {gray!10},
  row{even} = {white},
  row{1} = {gray!20},
} 
ID & P1  & P2 & P3 & P4 & P5 & P6 \\
1  &  x, age $\geq$ 18 & 62 (58) & 17.7\% (10.3\%) & 3 months & TY \\
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip\\
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip\\
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip\\
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip\\
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip\\
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip\\
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip\\
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip\\
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip\\
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip\\
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip\\
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip\\
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip\\
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip\\
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip\\
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip\\
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip\\
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip\\
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip\\
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip\\
minim & veniam quis & nostrud exercitation & ullamco & laboris & nisi ut & aliquip
\end{longtblr}
\twocolumn
}


\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: The resulting pages]

Comment: I think that's should be ok. Is there any better way to make a long table in two-column page where the table goes on page full page width? Maybe with tabular?

Comment: @molupq a tabular doesn't allow page breaks

Comment: Do you suggest any other way to create a long table in a two-column page?

Comment: @molupq No, I don't

Comment: That's wonderful... much needed, but hard to find for data science researchers. 
Editing for minimality and enhanced beauty.